# C++ : Send an object through a named pipe

Tags: c++, serialization, casting, named-pipes, fifo

I try to send an object through a named pipe, between two process, in C++ with ifstream and ofstream. I have read and try so many things but my research has led to nothing.

I block during the serialization of my object.
When I try to cast and send to my named pipe, I can not recover my object to his normale state.

I try something with this code but the object is not full after its passage in the named pipe :

```
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

class Obj {
public:
    std::string text1;
    std::string text2;
};

int main() {

    mkfifo("fifo", 0666);

    if (fork() == 0) //Receiving Side
    {

        std::ifstream fifo("fifo", std::ofstream::binary);

        //Re-make the object
        Obj *tmp = new Obj();
        char *b = new char[sizeof(*tmp)];

        //Receive from named pipe
        fifo >> b;

        //Recover the object
        memcpy(&*tmp, b, sizeof(*tmp));

        //Display object content
        std::cout << tmp->text1 << std::endl << tmp->text2 << std::endl;

        //!\ Output = "Some \n" /!\\

        fifo.close();
        delete tmp;
        delete[] b;
    }
    else //Sending Side
    {
        std::ofstream fifo("fifo", std::ofstream::binary);

        //Create the object
        Obj *struct_data = new Obj();
        struct_data->text1 = "Some text";
        struct_data->text2 = "Some text";

        char *b = new char[sizeof(*struct_data)];

        //Serialize the object
        memcpy((void *)b, &*struct_data, sizeof(*struct_data));

        //Send to named pipe
        fifo << b;

        fifo.close();
        wait(NULL);
        delete[] b;
    }

    //delete struct_data;
    return (0);
}
```

Does someone could give me a tip or en example ?

Thanks ! :)

Comment: Show us the serialization code. Is the byte format documented? If so, please show us the documentation. If not, document it. Trust me, it's worth the effort to document any protocol -- ideally before you code it.

Comment: When you say "cast and send" ... are you actually serializing, or just trying to send the raw bytes? And what does your object look like?

Comment: Your problem likely has nothing to do with pipes (named or not). You can try to make the sender write to stdout while the reader receive the object from stdin and connect them with `|`. Saves a lot of effort to setup the pipes and what not.

Comment: @Bross There's no code to serialize the object!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to serialize your object properly. Something like this (just did one member, the rest will be left as an excercise to the reader):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

class Obj
{
  public:
    std::string text1;
    std::string text2;

  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Obj& o);
  friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &os, Obj& o);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Obj& o)
{
  os << o.text1.length();
  os << o.text1;
  return os;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &is, Obj& o)
{
  size_t length;
  is >> length;
  char* tmp = new char[length];
  is.get(tmp, length+1); 
  o.text1 = tmp;
  delete[] tmp;
  return is;
}

static const char* myfifo = "myfifo";

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  mkfifo(myfifo, 0666);

  if (argc > 1)
  {       
    std::ifstream infifo(myfifo, std::ifstream::binary);

    Obj *tmp = new Obj();

    infifo >> *tmp; 
    infifo.close();

    std::cout << "Done reading : [" << tmp->text1 << "]" << std::endl;
  }
  else
  {
    std::ofstream outfifo(myfifo, std::ofstream::binary);

    Obj *struct_data = new Obj();
    struct_data->text1 = "Some text1";
    struct_data->text2 = "Some text2";

    outfifo << *struct_data;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

For more on serialization see https://stackoverflow.com/a/26337239/2742863

Comment: Some nitpicks: (1) why friend declaration of `operator>>` is  with `const`? (2) why not return `os` in `operator>>`? (3) why name the input stream `os` (which is a short for output stream, IIUC) in `operator>>`?

Comment: also, isn't `os.get(tmp, length+1);` an off-by-1 bug?

Comment: @OrenMilman, You are absolutely right, good naming is important for readability. There was some sloppy code there, that I think I have fixed now. I don't think there is an "off-by-1" bug. According to the documentation, (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/), get reads "until either (n-1) characters have been extracted".