# Deserialize bytes array in C++ which was serialized in C#

Tags: c++, arrays, deserialization, tcp

I have an array of [CameraSpacePoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.cameraspacepoint.aspx), which I have converted into bytes in C# programming language. The `CameraSpacePoint` is defined as follow:

```
namespace Microsoft.Kinect
{
    public struct CameraSpacePoint
    {
        public float X;
        public float Y;
        public float Z;
   }
}
```

To convert the array of `CameraSpacePoint` into bytes, I used the following method in C#:

```
public static byte[] ObjectToByteArray(Object obj)
{
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

The bytes array is then transferred using TCP.  I am trying to receive this byte array on the other machine in the following manner:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
constexpr size_t data_size = 512 * 424;
unsigned char data_buffer[data_size];
boost::asio::read(socket, boost::asio::buffer(data_buffer, data_size));
```

I declared a similar class in C++ as follow:

```
class CameraSpacePoint
{
public:
    float X;
    float Y;
    float Z;
};
```

I want to know that how to convert back byte array into my defined `CameraSpacePoint` object of array?

Comment: __How__ is it being serialized and transferred? Where is the _bytes array_ you mentioned?

Comment: General approach would be to use google Protocol Buffers. Another possibility is to use memcpy(&yourCppStruct, buffer, size); but this is not safe and not recommended.

Comment: @Ptaq666 How is that not safe if you are the sole owner of the serialization code?

Comment: @PasserBy, ok let's say that it might be difficult to debug if data in the buffer will not be consistent (for some reason).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Serializing object to byte-array in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26336414/serializing-object-to-byte-array-in-c)

Comment: @PasserBy : the data is being transferred using 'System.Net.Sockets' in C# on Windows 10. However the client is designed in C++ using 'boost::asio::connect(socket, endpoint);' on Ubuntu 14.04. Sever and client are able to communicate using string data. But I want to send array of 'CameraSpacePoint'. I am out of lab, hence can't send code now. Thank you very much.

Comment: As @sorush-r has answered, you should use a proper serialisation library. Protobuf, Cap'nProto, Avro, Thrift, MessagePack, FlatBuffers... there are plenty to choose from, but trying to just use bytes directly from memory is a bad idea.

Comment: @PasserBy: I added serialization code in the post. Please have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memory layout and serialization of objects in C# programming language has nothing to do with similar concepts in C/C++. Having different compilers/OSes, even in a C++ to C++ scenario you may get different memory layouts for same struct or class (according to memory layout, etc.).

What you really need is a common protocol for both languages to serialize and deserialize similar objects. There are some serialization libraries out there which support both languages:

- [Google's Protocol Buffers](https://github.com/google/protobuf) Supports both C# and C++, it's platform-neutral. (You can use it to serialize/deserialize between big-endian ARM and little-endian x86_64 for example)
- [Microsoft Bond](https://github.com/Microsoft/bond) Supports both C# and C++

Comment: Thank you very much. I liked [Google's Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/). However, I recently heard about [FlatBuffers](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/). Any comments about it?